# Manual says "Do not use the jack supplied with your vehicle" -- why is it?

Tags: toyota, oil-change, jack

I just bought an used Toyota Yaris 2008 hatchback and I'm preparing to change oil for the first time.

There's a jack supplied with the car (along the with spare tire). However, the manual seems to suggest that I should use a floor jack to jack up my car instead.

Is this just a legal thing where they just recommend the best thing possible, or is it an advice I should follow? If indeed it's good advice, then how could I jack up my car to change tire on the highway when only the supplied jack is available?

Comment: I would suggest simply getting some ramp to take the front higher to help get done with the oil change. Other have pretty mutch covered why you should not use your supplied jack to do this job

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure what it specifically says, but it is indeed not safe to be under a car that is supported only by a jack, hydraulic or mechanical.  To be safe, get a pair of jack stands, and use whatever jack you want to raise the car high enough to put the stands in place, then lower it so vehicle is resting on the stands.  The jack that comes with the car might not lift the car high enough to get the stands in place though.

Comment: I suppose the supplied jack is only to change tire then? (since I don't have to get underneath to change tire)

Comment: @Heisenberg: Exactly.

Answer (score 4):

The supplied car jack is for an emergency change of a wheel, pucture?, on firm ground, with the wheel nuts loosened before raising the vehicle, with the handbrake firmly applied. It is not intended for any other use. At no time put any part of yourself, or allow anybody else, under a vehicle raised on this type of jack.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to jack that car up to change oil. You can reach the oil filter easily from the front and you can reach the drain plug nearly as easily - also from the front - while the car rests on its wheels on the ground. Unless your arms are about ten times thicker than mine are, anyway.

In fact, you can reach the filter from the TOP, down past the intake. It's a little tough to get hold of it there, though, even with a socket-type filter wrench.